# How to add a ModelMultipleChoiceField to a model?

Tags: python, django, admin

How can I display my model in ModelMultipleChoiceField
I have models.py

```
# Модель заказа
class ProductsSet(models.Model):
    # Название набора
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="ID")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    products_set = models.ManyToManyField('ProductsInstance', related_name='sets') 
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class ProductsInstance(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          help_text="Unique ID")
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
```

И admin.py

```
@admin.register(ProductsInstance)
class ProductsInstanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product', 'price_for_client', 'borrower', 'coeff')
    list_filter = ('status','borrower',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('product', 'coeff', 'price_for_client', 'id')
        }),
        ('Availability', {
            'fields': ('status', 'borrower')
        }),
    )
    
@admin.register(ProductsSet)
class ProductsSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'borrower', 'created_date', 'status', 'total_amount')
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'products_set', 'created_date', 'borrower', 'status', 'total_amount']
    list_filter = ['borrower','created_date','status']
```

What does it look like for me now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVlXw.png)

And this is how I want it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjXq5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```java
class ProductsSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = []
 
        products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset=ProductsInstance.objects.all(),
         required=False,
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('products', False)
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductsSetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['products'].initial = self.instance.products_set.all()

    def save_m2m(self):
        self.instance.products_set.set(self.cleaned_data['products'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_amount = sum(product.price_for_client for product in self.products_set.all())
        instance = super(ProductsSetForm, self).save()
        self.save_m2m()
        return instance
    class ProductsSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
        form = ProductsSetForm 
        list_display = ('name', 'borrower', 'created_date', 'status', 'total_amount')
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'products_set','products', 'created_date', 'borrower', 'status', 'total_amount']
        list_filter = ['borrower','created_date','status']  
    admin.site.register(ProductsSet, ProductsSetAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You list the relation in the [**`filter_horizontal`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal):

```
@admin.register(ProductsSet)
class ProductsSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'borrower', 'created_date', 'status', 'total_amount')
    fields = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'products_set',
        'created_date',
        'borrower',
        'status',
        'total_amount',
    ]
    filter_horizontal = ['products_set']
    list_filter = ['borrower', 'created_date', 'status']
```

You can also use [**`filter_vertical`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical) where the two boxes appear above and below each other.

Comment: I solved my problem just an hour ago, but compared to your solution, mine is very cumbersome )). Thanks a lot